# How to Remove Powered By Google from Prediction in Flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-prediction

I want to know if is there any way I can remove powered by Google logo from Prediction plugin in Flutter.

[image: Img]

Thanks

Comment: I believe it is mandatory to show the google logo. -- If you insist on removing the logo, you could always try to clone/fork the plugin's repo and remove the logo manually and load your version from the pubspec instead.

Answer (score 6):

Pass an empty Text widget di the logo property

```
Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
        context: context,
        apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
        mode: Mode.overlay,
        language: "it",
        logo: Text(""),
        components: [Component(Component.country, "it")],
      );
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on the Terms of Service, it says: Attribution. Customer will display all attribution that (i) Google provides through the Services (including branding, logos, and copyright and trademark notices); or (ii) is specified in the Service Specific Terms. Customer will not modify, obscure, or delete such attribution.